# The variable (char) does not appear when entering the if condition - C

Tags: c, netbeans, cygwin

I'm new to C language and when trying to build this application on NetBeans, apparently there is no error when I will compile this function. However, when the user enters his name and gender, the application normally enters `IF`, `ELSE IF`, and `ELSE`, but when in `IF` and `ELSE IF`, the username does not appear in the printf () method.

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

ex19(){
    char name[100];
    char genre;

    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);

    printf("Enter your genre: ");
    scanf("%s", &genre);

    if (genre == 'M'){
        printf("%s you are a BOY", name);
    } 

    else if (genre == 'F'){
        printf("%s is GIRL", name);
    }

    else {
        printf("INVALID GENRE");
    }
}

main(){
    ex19();
}
```

What would be the problem with this algorithm? Sorry for any nonsense, I'm new to C programming and I'm risking learning this language without watching books or video lessons. For now, I'm doing well because of my previous knowledge of programming with Java, JavaScript, PHP and now with the C language. But what is going on in this code anyway?

Comment: `scanf("%s", &genre);` virtually guarantees a buffer overflow. `&genre` is an array of exactly one char, so it can only represent an empty string (recall that every string needs a terminating NUL character).

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `name` as an array of chars. A variable that’s of type array plays a role very similar to a pointer. In your `scanf` statement for `name`, you use `&name`, which is a pointer to that array. That takes it a level too far; remove the &.

Comment: While passing `&name` to `scanf` is a mistake, in common C implementations, the behavior would work the same as passing `name` to `scanf`. This answer does not explain the problem asked about in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What would be the problem with this algorithm?

The algorithm is fine....the problem seems arise from a culmination of

- where variables are stored in memory

  And
- the declaration of the variable `genre` as a `char` (designated to hold a single character of size one byte) and the subsequent attempt to read data into it as a *string*,`scanf("%s", &genre);`

Explanation:

When the code is executed the address of `genre` is one byte before the address of the array `char name[100];`

On entering the name, the name is placed in the character array `name`, as expected.
The subsequent `scanf` for the genre, stores the input at the location of genre but because the `%s` format specifier also adds a terminating `NULL('\0')` character. This 'NULL' character overwrites the first character in `name`. Now the very first character of `name` is the `'\0'` character.

Solution:

Either modify `scanf` to read a single character `scanf(" %c",&genre);`(the space before `%c` is required to consume the `newline` character).

Or

Change the declaration of `genre` to `char genre[2];` to include `M` or `F`, the `newline` character and the `'\0'`.

Hope this helps......

```
void ex19(){
  char name[100];
  char genre;

  printf("Enter your name: ");
  scanf("%s", name);

  printf("Enter your genre: ");
  scanf(" %c", &genre);//ignore whitespace characters and read a character

  if (genre == 'M'){
    printf("%s you are a BOY", name);
  } 

  else if (genre == 'F'){
    printf("%s is GIRL", name);
  }

  else {
    printf("INVALID GENRE");
  }
}
```

Or

```
void ex19(){
  char name[100];
  char genre[2];//declare genre as a character array

  printf("Enter your name: ");
  scanf("%s", name);

  printf("Enter your genre: ");
  scanf("%s", &genre);

  if (*genre == 'M'){//deference genre...same as genre[0]
    printf("%s you are a BOY", name);
  } 

  else if (*genre == 'F'){//deference genre...same as genre[0]
    printf("%s is GIRL", name);
  }

  else {
    printf("INVALID GENRE");
  }
}
```